# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'transformers'

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, importerror, huggingface-transformers

This is my first post and I am new to coding, so please let me know if you need more information. I have been running some AI to generate artwork and it has been working, but when I reloaded it the python script won't work and it is now saying "No module named 'transformers'". Can anyone help me out? It was when I upgraded to Google Colab Pro that I started to encounter issues although I am not sure why that would make a difference.

`ModuleNotFoundError`

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Probably it is because you have not installed in your (new, since you've upgraded to colabs pro) session the library transformers. Try to run as first cell the following: `!pip install transformers` (the "!" at the beginning of the instruction is needed to go into "terminal mode" ). This will download the transformers package into the session's environment.

Comment: Thank you! I was sure I already tried that but just plugged it in and it worked! thank you so much!

Comment: despite of !pip install transformers, i still get Requirement already satisfied: transformers  .....

Comment: @Manza "requirement already satisfied: transformers..." is good news, it's simply telling you that it's already installed.

Comment: @chattershuts yes i understand that but why the notebook will not run and why i would get that error?, having say that if i go dorectly into the terminal and do python >> import transformer, i dont get that error. Only in the notebook

Comment: @Manza sorry, but I do not understand what problem you are facing. "requirement already satisfied..." is not an error, it is a warning. it usually appears if you are trying to install a library, but that library is already installed. if my answer is not clear just let me know exactly what problem you are facing and we'll figure it out.

Comment: @chattershuts in my jupyter notebook when i go and say import transformer i get the same error of module not found,

Comment: Ok, and if you write "!pip install transformers" it doesn't fix the problem? 
Anyways you should show a reproducible code snippet/jupyter notebook , otherwise, it is difficult to understand what problem you are facing and why.

Comment: @chattershuts I'm having the exact same issue, I literally have the line `!pip install transformers peft datasets tqdm` above `from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM` but it still says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'` and the log says `Requirement already satisfied: transformers in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (4.37.2)`

Comment: Looks like the solution was to switch the kernel in the top right corner to the virtual env (in my case `venv`)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are referring to the module here https://pypi.org/project/transformers/
you need to install transformers with pip

```
pip install transformers
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some possible solutions

#### 1. Install the required package:

Run the following command

```
!pip install transformers
```

Or, if that doesn’t work, try

```
!pip3 install transformers
```

Please note the use of `!`, as it is a shell command, and not a python script.

#### 2. Start over with a new run-time:

Click `Runtime` > `Disconnect and delete runtime`

Then click `Runtime` > `Run all`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes your editor will confuse python interpreters.

Probably use

```
!python -m pip install transformers
```

Answer (score 0):

after you install transformers, make sure to import it , and import the Module youre gonna use

Answer (score 0):

If the already installed package shows in `!pip show transformers` but you still cannot `import transformers`, try **restarting Python** kernel (runtime) using Jupyter Lab/Notebook (Google Colab) menu.

This worked for me in Google Colab's GPU (T4) instance after installing `transformers` with `pip` initially produced the above error message during import attempts.

Answer (score 0):

if it does not work with pip, try installing it with anaconda:
conda install -c conda-forge transformers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35336922)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which environment you are installing the library in and which one you are using to run the cells. Perhaps this is the problem.

It's not very intuitive, and for some reason the notebook doesn't change the environment to the correct one automatically when switching

Even when you change the environment and run "!pip install transformers" in the cell, it will be installed in the originally selected environment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Even after I used this command (**pip install transformers**)  the terminal said,

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'*

But this solved it, in vscode terminal:

```
python -m pip install transformers
```