# How to fix "ValueError: This tokenizer cannot be instantiated. Please make sure you have `sentencepiece` installed in order to use this tokenizer."

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, valueerror

I'm trying to run a Hugging Face model using the following code in Google Colab:

```
!pip install transformers

from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-es")
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
```

And I'm having the following error:

```
ValueError: This tokenizer cannot be instantiated. Please make sure you have `sentencepiece` installed in order to use this tokenizer.
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: `!pip install transformers[sentencepiece]` or `!pip install sentencepiece` should solve it. A restart of the kernel might be needed.

Comment: a restart of the kernel is indeed needed, otherwise it won't work on google colab

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have **1) installed `sensencepiece`** correctly and it imports in Python, but it still does not work (as seen from error messages of downstream packages), then a **2) restart of the Python kernel** (called runtime in Colab) is required before the new package (here: `sentencepiece`) can be used.

I believe it's not just a Colab limitation, because I've encountered similar usage problems also in custom-build containers hosted on other servers, and with other newly installed packages (including transformers itself, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77145315/9962007)).

Make sure you read comments to the [question above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75595083/9962007), where both these steps were first suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`!pip install sentencepiece`

I encountered a similar problem, but I managed to resolve it by running the mentioned command and restarting my kernel.